# How to Update MYSQL table in PHP using JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, jstree

I am working with jstree. The tree works fine.I send JSON to a PHP file with JQuery. This works fine.

```
$("#button3").click(function(){
    //json object
    var objtree = $("#container").jstree(true).get_json('#', { 'flat' : true });
    var fulltree = JSON.stringify(objtree);
    var myarray = $.parseJSON(fulltree);
    var params = { myarray: myarray };
    var paramJSON = JSON.stringify(params);

    //sending to php file
    $.post('update.php',{ data: paramJSON });

});
```

Then in the php file (update.php), I update mySQL table by: deleting all the records in $tablename ($sql1) and inserting the information gotten from the JSON ($sql2). This works fine.

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $user,$password,$database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $test = $_POST["data"];
    $obj = json_decode($test, true);
    $data = $obj["myarray"];

    //first query
    $sql1 = "DELETE FROM $tablename";
    $connection ->query($sql2);

    foreach($data as $val){
        //second query
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO $tablename(id,parent,text) VALUES('".$val['id']."', '".$val['parent']."', '".$val['text']."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

But what I want is not to delete everything in the table then insert them brand new. But an SQL statement to update the old values (using the id maybe?) and insert the new values.

So like:

```
If id exists:
   update row
else:
   insert new row
```

I am new to PHP and SQL. So my problem is knowing the PHP syntax for accessing JSON array information. So please any example would be much appreciated!

Comment: See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html Also use parameterized queries. You're open to SQL injections.

Comment: There is just so much wrong here. Please use a framework, as it will protect you from countless SQL Injection vulnerabilities that your code is open to. You are trusting user input with no validation, building queries using string concatenation (use parameterized queries as @chris85 suggests). There are also quite a lot of syntax errors in the code above - not sure it would actually run to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll use a PHP function to get all rows matching the given ID. `if` this returns one, you'll use another function to `UPDATE`where the `ID == valueFromPreviousFunction`, `else` you'll call a function to `INSERT` a new row.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $check = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `your_table_name` WHERE `id`='".$val["id"]."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check)==1)
    {
        //Update the row
        $update = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE `table_name` SET `parent`='".$val["parent"]."', `text`='".$val["text"]."' WHERE `id`='".$val["id"]."'");
    }
    else
    {
        //Insert the row 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a command to do what you want in a single operation.

You should either fetch all ids beforehand and run an update for each one of them separately, or use [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html).

Be careful with REPLACE INTO, though: if a row matching a primary/unique key exists, it first deletes it and then inserts a new one rather than updating the existing row.